# If every ideal is principal show the same is true for the image of a homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I was working on a worksheet for class and came across this problem:

> Let $\varphi:R\to S$ be an onto ring homomorphism with the property that every ideal of $R$ is principal. Show that the same must be true for $S$.

I honestly do not know how to do this one!

Answer (score 4):

Claim: If $\varphi$ is a surjective homomorphism, the pullback of every ideal in $S$ is an ideal in $R$ (true always) and the image of every ideal in $R$ is an ideal in $S$ (true only in a surjective map).

Assuming that, given any ideal $J\subset S$, it pulls back to $Ra=I=\varphi^{-1}(J)$. Then we have $\varphi(I)=J$ is the same ideal, so $\varphi(I)=\varphi(R)\varphi(a)=S\varphi(a)=J$.

Comment: Is there a more algebraic way to prove this?  I'm not the best with ideal properties.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Properties of ideals are an algebraic issue.

Comment: I guess a more step-by-step proof. I just want to make sure that I really understand this.